# Simple Forecasting using Average method in R for Time series data for multiple groups

Tags: r, time-series, forecast

I've done  forecasting and time series analysis for individual values but not for group of values in one go. I've got a historical data (36 months- 1st day of each month which I created as required by time series) for multiple groups(Model No.) in a data frame which looks like below:

```
ModelNo.       Month_Year      Quantity
a               2017-06-01         0
a               2017-07-01         5
a               2017-08-01         3
..              ..........         ....
..              ..........         ....
a               2020-05-01         6

b               2017-06-01         9
b               2017-07-01         0
b               2017-08-01         1
..              ..........         ....
..              ..........         ....         
b               2020-05-01         4

c               2020-05-01         3
c               2017-06-01         1
c               2017-07-01         1
c               2017-08-01         0
..              ..........         ....
..              ..........         ....         
c               2020-05-01         4
```

I then use the below code to subset my data frame for "one group" to generate forecast using simple average function

```
Selected_data<-subset(data, ModelNo.=='a')

currentMonth<-month(Sys.Date())
currentYear<-year(Sys.Date())
```

I then create the time series object for 24 months which i then input to my forecast function.

```
y_ts = ts(Selected_data$Quantity, start=c(currentYear-3, currentMonth), end=c(currentYear-1, currentMonth-1), frequency=12)
```

I then use simple mean function for forecasting the 12 months value (which I already have "quantity" valuesfor , june 2019-may 2020)

```
 meanf(y_ts, 12, level = c(95))
```

and I get a output like for my data (not the output linked to above data provide, just a snapshot of my original data)

```
         Point Forecast     Lo 95    Hi 95
Jun 2019          1.875 -3.117887 6.867887
Jul 2019          1.875 -3.117887 6.867887
Aug 2019          1.875 -3.117887 6.867887
Sep 2019          1.875 -3.117887 6.867887
Oct 2019          1.875 -3.117887 6.867887
Nov 2019          1.875 -3.117887 6.867887
Dec 2019          1.875 -3.117887 6.867887
Jan 2020          1.875 -3.117887 6.867887
Feb 2020          1.875 -3.117887 6.867887
Mar 2020          1.875 -3.117887 6.867887
Apr 2020          1.875 -3.117887 6.867887
May 2020          1.875 -3.117887 6.867887
```

So I'm able to successfully generate forecast for "one" Model No. here.  However, my question are :

1. I have to generate this forecast for all groups in my dataframe, like a , b,  c and so on. So I don't know how to do this and store the result in a new data frame for forecast values along with Dates for each ModelNo.

I know if i use below , that will return me the forecasted values R function meanf the output shows

```
meanf(y_ts, 12, level = c(95))$mean
```

But how to store its for each group type against dates in a dataframe, I tried mutate() it didnt work.

2. Following on Question 1,  how should I then compare the forecast values with the actual values (as you can see I only sliced 24 months data to predict 12 month values). I know there are methods in R and time series analysis where I can use multiple historical slicing test and train window and then check and compare with actual values to measure forecast results/accuracy etc. I plan to expand this to use and try multiple forecasting methods.

Please if someone can help me with the above two questions.

I believe there is a learning curve required , I know partially the process but I'm not sure how systematically I can fill this knowledge gap to use forecasting methods for multiple groups and test them against actual values. Apart from the answers to the above two questions any link to a tutorial with which I can enhance my learning will be very helpful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question(s) is rather broad, so you can start with something like this to think about how to proceed. First of all you did not provide some reproducible data, so I used what you've posted, with some tweak to your code to make it works. The idea is to do for each model a train and a test time series, create the forecast, and store it in a `data.frame`. Then you can calculate for example RMSE to see the goodness of fit on test.

```
library(forecast)
library(lubridate)

# set date limits to train and test
 train_start <- ymd("2017-06-01")
 train_end <- ymd("2019-05-01")

 test_start <- ymd("2019-06-01") # end not necessary

# create an empty list
listed <- list()

for (i in unique(data$ModelNo.))
                   {
                    # subset one group
                      Selected_data<-subset(data, ModelNo.==i)
                    # as ts
                      y_ts <- ts(Selected_data$Quantity,
                                 start=c(year(min(data$Month_Year)),
                                         month(max(data$Month_Year))),
                                 frequency=12)

                    # create train
                      train_ts <- window(y_ts, 
                                        start=c(year(train_start), month(train_start)), 
                                         end=c(year(train_end), month(train_end)), frequency = 12)
                    # create test (note: using parameters ok to your sample data)
                       test_ts <- window(y_ts, 
                                         start=c(year(test_start), month(test_start)), frequency = 12)

                    listed[[i]] <- cbind(
                        data.frame(meanf(train_ts,length(test_ts),level = c(95))),
                        real =as.vector(test_ts)) 
                  }
```

Now for part 1, you can create a data.frame with the results:

```
res <- do.call(rbind,listed)
head(res) # only head to simplify output
           Point.Forecast     Lo.95    Hi.95 real
a.Jun 2019       49.29167 -22.57528 121.1586   95
a.Jul 2019       49.29167 -22.57528 121.1586   93
a.Aug 2019       49.29167 -22.57528 121.1586    5
a.Sep 2019       49.29167 -22.57528 121.1586   66
a.Oct 2019       49.29167 -22.57528 121.1586   47
a.Nov 2019       49.29167 -22.57528 121.1586   40
```

For point 2, you can calculate RMSE (there is an handy function in package Metrics) for each time series:

```
library(Metrics)
goodness <- lapply(listed, function(x)rmse(x$real, x$Point.Forecast))
goodness 
    $$a
[1] 31.8692

$b
[1] 30.69859

$c
[1] 30.28037
```

---

With data:

```
   set.seed(1234)
data <- data.frame(ModelNo. = c(rep("a",36),rep("b",36),rep("c",36)),
           Month_Year = lubridate::ymd(rep(seq(as.Date("2017/6/1"), by = "month", length.out = 36),3)),
           Quantity =sample(1:100,108, replace = T)
           )
```

Comment: Hi @Gayatri, I've edited the question adding data similar as you've described, and adding some mods to the script to get the train and testing as you stated. The idea behind is the same, there are only some tweaks. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey s_t this actually works , thank you very much for sharing the code.Will you be able to provide some liunk where i can learn more time series methods , as i need to do the same not just for average/meanf forecasting but also other forecasting methods like holt winters etc. where I can use some parameter (alpha beta gamma ) tuning. Thank you very much. How can share my updated code and result output

Comment: You're welcome, try [this link](https://otexts.com/fpp2/), it's a good source to me.

Comment: Hi s_t, I'm trying to use the rolling mean method now for the same data (group of data above) using the code `y_ts <- ts(Data_sort$Quantity,
          start=c(year(min(Data_sort$Month_Year)), month(max(Data_sort$Month_Year))+1), frequency=12)
View(y_ts) #### 36 months original time series day

rollwindow=24   ##### so that I my first rolling average value is for 25th month

forecast<-  rollmean(y_ts, rollwindow, align = "right", fill=NA)'
 My issue is the data gets populated from 24th month and not 25th month onwads although the values are calculated correctly  for 24 months moving avg.

Comment: Hi Gaytri you should open a new question on SO to get an answer: I don't want to be pedantic, but this is how it works this community.

Comment: HI t_s, here is my question if you can please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62759128/how-to-use-configurable-moving-average-for-forecasting-in-r